# Paste event not functioning properly in Opera 11 and lower versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, paste

I am trying out this simple code which is supposed to shift the focus to another text box when a right click is detected on the first, so that any subsequent `paste` event makes the text to be pasted into the 2nd box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#real").bind("contextmenu",function() {
           $("#paste").focus();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = 'text' sh = '0' right = '0' id = 'real' />
    <input type = 'text' id = 'paste' />
    <p>Dummy</p>
</html>
```

In Opera above versions 12, it is working fine. However, in 11 and below, even though the focus does get shifted to the 2nd text box on right clicking on the first, the paste event pastes the text in the first textbox (with the focus being shifted to the 2nd textbox immediately, on its own). I tried to replace the code by `setTimeout(function() { $("#paste").focus(); },0);`, still the error persists.

Can anyone tell me how do I fix this, so that the text gets pasted in the 2nd textbox? (Detecting a `mouseup`, checking whether it's a right click through `event.which`, if so, shift the focus - yeah, I did that too, same result!)

Comment: Do you really need to support Opera 11? It's dying out fast.

Comment: Yep, old fashioned clients..:(

Comment: I don't understand the full scope of your requirements here. Do you want to make it possible to type into the 'real' box, but if something is pasted it should go into the 'paste' box? Or should all input into 'real' end up in 'paste'? Why do you have two boxes in the first place?

Comment: What I need to do is this. I need to ensure that the client is not able to input any character other than numbers. Normal keypress is easy to intercept, the `paste` event is finicky. Even though I can let him paste whatever he wants, followed by a timer which finds whether the value pasted is number or not, if not, delete, I don't want the non-digits be visible even for a split second. SO what I am doing is this: on contextmenu event, I am shifting the focus to the hidden textbox. So the paste gets pasted there. It has a paste handler, which then runs.

Comment: If the text that has been pasted there is a numeric chunk, then paste it back to the original box. Else, do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution...

```
$("#real").bind("contextmenu",function() {
    $("#paste").val($(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: No, I don't want the pasted text to be visible even for a split second before going through some filtering in the 2nd textbox (which is invisible..:))